# .slideToggle not working

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

I know I have the files linked right, because it shows up in inspector on Chrome. Here's my HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html>
        <head>
          <title>jQuery</title>
          <script type='text/javascript' src='jquery-1.7.2.min.js'></script>
          <script type='text/javascript' src='scripts/change.js'></script>
        </head>
        <body>
          <p>
            <button id="start">Start</button>
            <button id="stop">Stop</button>
          </p>
          <p id="image">
            <img src='images/image.jpg' alt="image" />
          </p>
        </body>
      </html>
```

jQuery:

```
      $('#start').click(function() {
        $('#image').slideToggle(3000);
      });
```

Comment: Umm, it's working just fine for me.

Answer (score 5):

You need to wrap your whole code within `$(document).ready()` handler. So, the it insures that, the code will bind to dom after whole resources load finish.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#start').click(function() {
    $('#image').slideToggle(3000);
  });
});
```

#### Note

Check that your path to external JavaScript files are ***OK***.

Comment: Oh, I couldn't imagine he hadn't done that!

Comment: Thank you! That worked! I am 12 years old... Still learning...